# Django: Making python script run on button click and display output on html page

Tags: python, django

I have been working on making a python script that will run by clicking a button and then displaying the output in the Django html page. so far I have managed to make a button that will run the script but I am not able to display any results below is the code I have used, it runs the python script in shell but goes no further.

In my Views.py

```
def Yellow(request):
    inp = request.POST.get('param')

    out = run(['python', '/yellow_page_updated.py', inp], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    print(out.stderr)
    print("Finished!!")
    return render('Yellow_Page.html', {'data1': out})
```

In my Urls.py

```
url(r'^Yellow', views.Yellow, name="Yellow")
```

if anybody can help or point me in the right direction i would be very grateful.

if ant other info is needed please let me know

Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Note that when you run the script and check stderr, it is possible that the script is not done yet, so the error has not been printed either. Also, if you want to capture the error output, you can't also redirect it to /dev/null. Would suggest using subprocess.check_call() rather than subprocess.run(). It's less flexible but has fewer of these sharp edges.

Comment: what are you able to see on the console for "print(out.stderr)"